# Calling a getter method within a JPA entity from a play framework form makes a call to the setter function

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0

I am writing a simple play framework application with authentication where in passwords are hashed using BCrypt.

In simple words, my question is this : I have observed that in JPA entities, when you call the get method of a property, its set method is also somehow called..This is a problem if i am doing a non-idempotent operation within the set method.

I will describe a simplified example of my problem here

**This is my Login View**

```
    @helper.form(routes.Application.authenticate) {
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <ul id="login_box">
            <li>
                <span class="loginbox_label">Username : </span>
                <input type="text" class="login_input" id="usernm-input" name="email" value='@form("email").value' placeholder="Enter Username..." />
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="loginbox_label">Password : </span>
                <input type="password" class="login_input" id="passwd-input" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
            </li>
            <li>
            @if(form.hasGlobalErrors) { 
                <p class="error">
                    @form.globalError.message
                </p>
            }   
            </li>
        </ul>            
        <hr />
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.href = '@routes.Application.forgotpwd()?usr='+$('#usernm-input').val()" class="forgotpwdlink">Retrieve Forgotten Password</a>
        <input type="submit" class="alt_btn login_btn" value="Login" />     
        <hr />
}
```

On Submit it goes to the authenticate function

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result authenticate(){  
  
Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();    

    if(loginForm.hasErrors())
    {
        return badRequest(index.render(loginForm));
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Save Email to session
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);
    
        //Redirect to dashboard
        return redirect(routes.Application.showDashboard());
    }
}
```

**This is my Login Class**

```
public static class Login 
{   
public String email;
public String password;

public String validate() 
{      
  User usr = User.findByEmail(email);
  
  if(usr == null)
    return MessageStrings.USER_NOT_FOUND; //User Not Found
  
  
  if(usr.getPassword().equals(this.password))
  {
      return MessageStrings.NO_ERROR; //NO ERROR
  }
  else
  {
      return usr.getPassword();//MessageStrings.PASSWORD_MISMATCH; //Wrong Password
  }
 }      
}
```

As you can see,I am nowhere calling the usr.setPassword method. Also, I am returning the usr.getPassword() in the else part to return it and display it on the page instead of the error message.

**Finally, this is my User Class, a JPA entity**

```
@Transient
@Constraints.Required
@Formats.NonEmpty
private String password;

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(name = "password")    
public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password){       
    this.password = password + "1";//BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
```

Link to the complete JPA entity : http://pastebin.com/HZDEyYHZ

I only added the relevant part of the code here. Now looking at the code, you would figure that each time I submit the form it must just return the stored password(because I return usr.getPassword() in the else part). Notice the **this.password = password + "1";**.

Now if i keep submitting with incorrect password..this is what i am getting
[image: Capture]

**Clearly the setPassword is being repeatedly called whenever I submit the login form**

Why is this happening?

**A very lengthy post, I know**

Comment: in the screenshot 'qwe123' is the actual password but on each call to authenticate, the set is being called therby slowly changing the password in the db itself.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitely chose property access for your entity. This means that the setters are called to populate your entity. But your setter is not really a setter. So rename this method to something else, and add a real setter, or use field access rather than property access.

IMHO, hashing the password should not be done by the entity, and even less by a setter. The expected behavior is that the getter should return the value that has been set by the setter.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to hash it at the business logic level.